# VHDL Error: Coudl not Implement register on this clock edge

Tags: vhdl

I want to reset the variable `v_count` to 0 at the rising-edge of input 
port `i_pulse_run`. But I get the following errors:

> Error: Could not Implement register on this clock edge.
>   Error (10821): HDL error at PWM_Gen.vhd(85): can't infer register for 
>   "CTRL:v_count[15]" because its behavior does not match any supported 
>   register model.

How else can I reset the variable to 0. I want to reset it only at the 
rising edge of signal `i_pulse_run`.

Any suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.all;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
..
..
..
CTRL : PROCESS(i_Reset, i_Clock,i_pwm_pulse_run)

variable v_PWMout        : std_logic;          
variable v_intPWMvalue    : integer range 0 to 8192;  
variable  v_updatePWMvalue  : std_logic;          
variable v_count : integer range 0 to 65535;

begin
if i_Reset = '0' then
  -- Asynchronous reset
  o_PWM        <= '0';
  s_PWMCounter     <= 0;
  v_updatePWMvalue  := '0';
elsif rising_edge(i_Clock) then
-- Increment the PWM counter

   if s_PWMCounter < i_PWM_Freq_Div - 1 then
      s_PWMCounter   <= s_PWMCounter + 1;
   else
      s_PWMCounter   <= 0;
      if rising_edge(i_pulse_run) then
          v_count := 0; -- Error 
      end if;
      if i_pwm_pulse_en = '1' AND  v_count < i_pulse_count +1 then
         v_count := v_count + 1;
      end if;
end if;

..
..
end if;
end process CTRL;
```

Answer (score 1):

D-Flops are only sensitive to the rising edge of one clock. In your case, you don't actually want it to change on the rising edge of i_pulse_run because the rest of your circuit is clocked off i_clock; what you should do is have another register saving the value of `i_pulse_run` on each clock cycle, and then when the input value of `i_pulse_run` != saved `i_pulse_run`, you are on the rising edge.

Comment: I think you mean when `i_pulse_run = '1' and i_pulse_run_saved = '0'`, not just when they differ.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to design a register that updates on the simultaneous rising edges of i_Clock and i_pulse_run. Avoid nested edges.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

`begin
if i_Reset = '0' then
  -- Asynchronous reset
  o_PWM        <= '0';
...
elsif rising_edge(i_Clock) then
   ---This is what is important
   i_pulse_run_prev <= i_pulse_run;
   ---!!----------------------------
-- Increment the PWM counter
   if s_PWMCounter < i_PWM_Freq_Div - 1 then
      s_PWMCounter   <= s_PWMCounter + 1;
   else
      s_PWMCounter   <= 0;
      if rising_edge_pulse_run then
          v_count := 0; 
      elsif i_pwm_pulse_en = '1' AND  v_count < i_pulse_count +1 then
         v_count := v_count + 1;
      end if;
end if;
end process CTRL;`

rising_edge_pulse_run <= i_pulse_run and not i_pulse_run prev;